# QQ Boo binary star

Tags: binary-star

I need infos about this binary star, QQ Boo, when did it discovered, infos about each star in the binary system and infos about its light curve. I have already search through simbad and aavso websites But not enough infos there.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need information on QQ Boötis specifically? It doesn't seem to be a well-studied system.

Comment: It is among one of the binary that I study as a project

Comment: It would be helpful to know why this particular system was chosen for your project. It's also not clear what you mean by "infos", what details do you actually want? Bear in mind that it's a pretty obscure system (doesn't seem to have gotten much attention beyond catalogue entries), so that information may not even exist.

Answer (score 1):

Based on information from [Simbad](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=QQ%20Boo&submit=SIMBAD%20search), QQ Boo is an eclipsing variable at ICRS coordinates      15 32 04.8205703705 +45 34 07.427803308. Given [the bibliography](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%40497240&Name=V*%20QQ%20Boo&submit=display%20all%20measurements#lab_bib) for this object, it  was apparently [discovered in 2006](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/498016).

Based on [the first article](http://www.astronet.ru/db/varstars/msg/eid/PZP-06-0016) in the list, QQ Boo can also be named GSC 3483-01409 and has a period of 0.27648 days. At the same link, you can also find the [light curve](http://images.astronet.ru/pubd/2019/09/25/0001498501/29.jpg) and the [sky chart](http://images.astronet.ru/pubd/2019/09/25/0001498501/chart29.jpg), along with other information.

[image]

This star was also observed in the [Gaia DR2](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018yCat.1345....0G/abstract).

Comment: Thanks, is there any article or website that I can find infos in more details, like which star in binary system is hotter or smaller than the other?  Or if there are planets around it or about O-C graph.